# :Before psuedo-element same height as non-relative parent

Tags: css, css-position, pseudo-element

I am trying to create a CSS class that will mark an element as 'modified'. A modified element is indicated by a vertical line in the left-hand margin of the page body.

I am using a `:before` pseudo-element, but because my element does not have position relative, I can't seem to get it to match the same height as the parent.

Adding `position:relative` would allow me to match the height, but not align the marker relative on the left as the element may have padding/margin which means the left-margin is not aligned with the body.

I have made a quick Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5k8ruahm/5/

What I'm asking probably can't be achieved just using CSS, but before resorting to JavaScript, I thought I would ask here.

Comment: submitted an answer but not sure if that would work because of the left padding/margin you're saying you want aligned? You didn't include any other content so I'm not sure what it needs to align to. If my answer doesn't work, feel free to let me know why or give more context and I'll try to come up with another solution. Added another paragraph if that's what you want it to align with https://jsfiddle.net/5k8ruahm/2/ but `position: absolute` seems to work fine here, too https://jsfiddle.net/5k8ruahm/4/

Comment: Thanks Michael. My original Fiddle didn't illustrate the problem because it was too simple. I have added a more realistic version of my HTML/CSS and updated it: https://jsfiddle.net/5k8ruahm/5/

Comment: could you just disable the margin on `figure.modified`? https://jsfiddle.net/5k8ruahm/6/

Comment: Even if I did that, from the fiddle the red marker is still not positioned on the left-margin of the content div, which is where it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `.modified` a `flex` parent, and it will stretch each child (the content and `:before`) to match the height of the parent by default. Then use `translateX()` to move the line beside the parent.

```css
.content {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.modified {
  display: flex;
}

.modified:before {
  content: "\a0";
  border-left: 3px solid #f00;
  transform: translateX(-1em);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p class="modified">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in ipsum ac nisl commodo dapibus posuere sit amet lorem. Sed pulvinar dui purus, sed sollicitudin tortor efficitur eget. Maecenas et tempus tortor, ut maximus nunc. Proin pretium varius
    consectetur. Quisque dignissim eros nec odio ornare interdum. Praesent quis dui eget libero tempus venenatis vitae eu massa. Ut orci neque, sodales in nisi quis, pretium ultrices risus.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution https://jsfiddle.net/5k8ruahm/3/

Parent position changed to relative so you can define a `top:0;` and `bottom:0;` to the `:before` element

```
   .content
{
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.modified:before
{
  content: "\a0";
  border-left: 3px solid #f00;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your parent container as position:relative and the :before as absolute. Then apply the positioning to the :before pseudoclass. This should grant you the positioning you are looking for.